# Select everything in a database WHERE & order by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm doing the following query...

```
Status.where(:status => params[:cat_id])
```

but I want to order the results by the created_at column. I've tried everything logical like

```
Status.where(:status => params[:cat_id]), :order => "created_at DESC"
```

and

```
Status.where(:status => params[:cat_id], :order => "created_at DESC")
```

but nothing seems to work.

What's the best way to order results that you're getting from a where query?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Status.where(:status => params[:cat_id]).order("created_at DESC")
```

You might want to give a look at the [ActiveRecord API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can do using symbol:

```
.order(created_at: :DESC)
```